# Objective C equivalent of cURL to work with JSON

Tags: ios, json, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I tried to search around but can't find the exact answer.

My friend implements the website to return data in JSON by using cURL as below

```
curl http://example.com//api/v1/opens_set_current_position -d '{"latitude":"53.041", "longitude":"-2.90545", "radius":"100000"}' -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json"
```

I tried to write code to make my iOS app to retrieve data. But I can't. I always get error the data can't even load via NSURLConnection.
Here is my code:

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"http://example.com//api/v1/opens_set_current_position"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[req addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSString *dataString = @"{\"latitude\":\"53.041\", \"longitude\":\"-2.90545\", \"radius\":\"100000\"}";

NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[dataString UTF8String] length:[dataString length]];

[req setHTTPBody:requestData];

NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;
NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
```

The data didn't come at all. I get this error message:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)

Can somebody help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858110/nsurlconnection-closes-early-on-get

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are passing a body in a `GET` request.  You want a `POST` request instead.

From the `curl` manpage:

```
-d/--data <data>
(HTTP)  Sends  the  specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form
and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the
server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. When if I set the httpMethod to "POST",the (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" disappeared but I still not able to get what I wanted ,the data return with "500" code. It seems to be the problem with the server side.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @KongHantrakool I think I've answered the question you asked.